# Ember- integration test case on action

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-testing

In ember controller

```
action:function(){
  a:function(){
   ....
   this.set('b',true);  
  }
}
```

I just want to write a test case for this

```
test('a - function test case', function(assert) {
  var controller= this.subject();
  controller._action().a();
  assert(controller.get(b),true);
});
```

but this not working I'm getting undefined error.

any other way to pass this test case?

Comment: Are you trying to use [ember actions](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/)? If so, you have to use `actions: { ... }` instead of `action: function() {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your code, I believe you're trying to use [ember actions](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/), if so you have to use `actions: { ... }` instead of `action: function() { ... }`.

And to trigger an action you use the [send method](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ActionHandler.html#method_send).

This is an example on how to test an action in ember-cli:

*app/controllers/index*

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  value: null,
  actions: {
    changeValue: function() {
      this.set('value', true);
    }
  }
});
```

*tests/unit/controllers/index-test.js*

```
import {
  moduleFor,
  test
} from 'ember-qunit';

moduleFor('controller:index', {});

test('it exists', function(assert) {
  var controller = this.subject();
  assert.ok(!controller.get('value'));
  controller.send('changeValue');
  assert.ok(controller.get('value'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was working for me

```
test('it exists', function(assert) {
  var controller = this.subject();
  assert.ok(!controller.get('value'));
   Ember.run(function(){  
     controller.send('changeValue');
      assert.ok(controller.get('value'));
   });
});
```